# Extensions method with generic return is not being recognized and causes CS1061 Error

Tags: generics, c#-3.0, extension-methods

I tried to implement the extension method for converting ArrayList object to a List. I referred to [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-arraylist-list).

```
namespace MyProjects.Extensions
{
    static class ArrayListExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ArrayList => List<T>
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Based on http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-arraylist-list
        /// </remarks>
        public static List<T> ToListCollection<T>(this ArrayList arrayList)
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>(arrayList.Count);
            foreach (T instance in arrayList)
            {
                list.Add(instance);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use it, I made sure that I added a `using MyProjects.Extensions` clause but it is still not recognized. Any ideas?

```
ArrayList arrTest = Settings.Default["ListA"] as ArrayList;
arrTest.ToListCollection<MyCustomObject>();
```

Comment: Is the extension method in a different assembly? If so, see answer below.

Comment: You realize your extension method is effectively `return arrayList.Cast<T>().ToList()` right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your extension class `public` and try. If its in different namespace it is not accessible to your current project. By default if there is no access modifier specified class are `internal`.

Do something like this

```
namespace MyProjects.Extensions
{
    public static class ArrayListExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ArrayList => List<T>
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Based on http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-arraylist-list
        /// </remarks>
        public static List<T> ToListCollection<T>(this ArrayList arrayList)
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>(arrayList.Count);
            foreach (T instance in arrayList)
            {
                list.Add(instance);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about [Access Modifiers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).

**Note**: Referred site has a demo in which the extension class is defined in same namespace as the consumer.

Alternatively you can use `arrayList.Cast<T>().ToList()` (from [Jon Skeet'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)s comment).

Hope this helps you.